# Sometimes get data and sometime gives an error which is not valid json in Angularjs with Laravel 5.7? Looking For Answer

Tags: php, angularjs, angular6, laravel-5.7

I am working in laravel 5.7 along with angularjs. I receive the data but sometimes it gives me data and sometime it gives me an error which is data is not valid json form, parse {} error. Below is my  angularjs code

```
$http({
      method: "GET",
      url : "get-portlanding" //Laravel route
}).then(function(response){
      $scope.portlanding= response.data;
});
```

Below is laravel controller code.

```
public function GetPortLanding(){

     $result = Portlanding::all();
     return response->json($result);
}
```

Below is error picture
What am i doing wrong can anyone help me out of this headache. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Look at variable name $resutl  and "return response->json($result);"

Comment: No sorry, i have typed incorrectly while posting question, but it's not the problem, let me fix it.

Comment: Check the server error log to find what is causing the error.

Comment: I have checked everything but don't know why it's not working. I have already mentioned that it gives me data as well as it also gives me error but sometime.

Comment: When i check the network in browser it shows me error in laravel route which says `"message": "server error"`